# callback is not a function inside async library

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async.js

I created this small code to reproduce the error I was getting inside an app:

```
const async = require("async");

function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

const parallels = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
  parallels.push(async function (callback) {
    const randomSleepTime = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 10000);
    await sleep(randomSleepTime);
    callback(randomSleepTime);
  });
}

async.parallel(parallels, function (err, results) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log(results);
});
```

I'm getting this error after this is done: `TypeError: callback is not a function`

Why exactly is this happening?

Comment: delete async. a callback is already async.

Comment: Why are you using *async.js*  instead of promises?

Comment: @zyrup I need it to run an await inside the function that will be fired in parallel with others (`await sleep()`)

Comment: @Bergi Is there any way to achieve running a loop that has an await in it in parallel through promises? Would appreciate it if you could share a link because I can't seem to find anything.

Comment: @CedricHadjian Create an array of promises in your loop, then use `Promise.all`

Comment: Just use `Promise.all()` to run things in parallel. If you need things like `parallelLimit()` you can use the promisified version of async.js - async-q: https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-q

Comment: @Bergi Can I pass async/await actions inside `Promise.all()`? I remember trying `Promise.allSettled()` it and it failed somehow.

Comment: @CedricHadjian No, you need to pass promises not actions (async functions).

Comment: @CedricHadjian don't use await sleep, just sleep

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to return the value instead of using `callback()` which is mentioned [here](https://github.com/caolan/async/issues/1584#issuecomment-439450756).